# WebForms Passing CheckboxList Values To List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, arrays, webforms

I have a GridView which I have a List bound to - I want to be able to allow filter of the data based on multiple CheckBoxLists.

For arguments sake let's say I have a List of Jobs, and I want to filter the jobs by code - So I would have a CheckBoxList like

- C#
- ASP.NET
- php
- F#
- etc..

If someone selects multiple codes, how do you pass the values into a List to rebind to the GridView?   Is there a way to pass values as an array? Or maybe a comma seperated string?

Any examples (I'm a C# boy) would be greatly appreciated, and I hope I have explained it properly :S

Comment: is it win / web application and which .net version you are using?

Comment: Sorry its webforms, .NET 4 c#..  Do you have any code examples for webforms

Answer (score 0):

use an `ObservableCollection<T>` . it automatically allows the gridview to "*observe*" that the underlying datasource has changed and thus update itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it doesn't answer the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question. But I often do the following to get ListItems into a form queryable via LINQ to objects:

```
var items = cblLanguages.Items.Cast<ListItem>();

// Selected Items
var selectedItems = items.Where(li => li.Selected);

// Item's containing 'C'
var itemsWithC = items.Where(li => li.Text.Contains("C"));

// Values between 2 and 5
var itemsBetween2And5 = from li in items
                        let v = Convert.ToInt32(li.Value)
                        where 2 <= v && v <= 5
                        select li;
```

Answer (score 0):

wherever you do your filtering for the gridview you have to build the list manually before you filter.

```
var languages = new List<string>();
foreach (ListItem item in cblLanguages.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        languages.Add(item.Value);
    }
}
```

then when you filter you can do something like (example using linq2sql)

```
var jobs = db.Jobs.Where(x => langauges.Contains(x.LanguageCode));
gvJobs.DataSource = jobs;
gvJobs.DataBind();
```